# Restrict access of a method on three object from three thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have been asked a question in an interview.
The question is as described below :
There is a class `Employee` which has a method in it called `getDetail()`.
We make three object of this class say `e1`, `e2` and `e3` and pass it to three different thread say `t1`, `t2` and `t3`.
Now start threads.
How can we restrict the threads to access `getDetail` method so that only one thread can access the method at a time.
I mean to say that if `t1` is inside `getDetail` method then no other thread can access the `getDetail` method of `Employee` class.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can mark method as [`synchronized`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) like this

```
class Employee {
    synchronized Detail getDetail() { ... }
}
```

However in the case you described there is no need in synchronization because each thread has its own instance of `Employee`. But you will need it if instances will be shared between threads or `Employee` class has `static` variables or classes shares some data inside them.
This can cause the problem even when each thread has its own instance.

In the last case there also can be a problem if method returns some complex object let's call it `EmployeeDetail`. When you will call `getDetail()` you will receive the reference to `EmployeeDetail` object that can be not thread safe. So additionaly you will need to make whole `EmployeeDetail` class thread safe.

If you need other methods like `setDetail(EmployeeDetail)` then you can mark them `synchronized`, that will correctly set `EmployeeDetail` reference.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, I believe there is no sense in making the threads restricting the `getDetails` method, assuming it is object level method. since each thread is given a different object. There is no change of cross over.

A better way to put the question would be, to pass same object to different threads and ask how does it affect the properties of the object, more over what is the point of accessing `getDetails()`, which just returns values. Better restrict access on the methods that change the properties of the object.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Threading {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Employee e1 = new Employee("e1");

        ArrayList<Employee> emps = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        emps.add(e1);

        ThreadEmployee t = new ThreadEmployee(emps);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(t);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(t);

        t1.setName("t1");
        t2.setName("t2");

        t1.start(); t2.start();
        t1.join(); t2.join();

        for(Employee e: emps)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getDetail());
        }
    }
}

class ThreadEmployee implements Runnable {
    private ArrayList<Employee> emps;

    ThreadEmployee(ArrayList<Employee> emps) {
        this.emps = emps;
    }

    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(Employee e: emps)
        {
            e.changeDetail(e.getDetail() + "-" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }
}

class Employee {
    private String name;

    Employee() {

    }

    Employee(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDetail() {
        return name;
    }

    synchronized public void changeDetail(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Even I am not aware of how actually threads execute it's completely in the hands of JVM, but towards the end I can be sure that only one object will access changeDetails method at a time. There would not be any misrepresentation of data.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. As I know synchronization works on same object, but here objects are different. I answered the same but it interviewer was not satisfied with the answer.
My answer was thread safety concerns only when different threads are accessing the same object. here each thread has a separate object.

Comment: I have just given an example as getDetail. It could be any method which may be setting any value to employee or updating any value.

Comment: @Rajeev I do not know what was the interviewer thinking posing such question.